# MonoDevelop Insert Mode always on?

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, keyboard-shortcuts, monodevelop

I've updated to the latest versions of MonoTouch and MonoDevelop.

I can't seem to highlight ensure rows of text at a time by using the shift key + up/down arrows. I've also noticed that "--INSERT--" appears in the bottom left status bar. The cursor is also a box instead of the usually single line.

I'm using a mac book pro, so there is no insert key, and pressing fn + return doesn't seem to have any effect.

How do I turn insert mode on and off?

I've also noticed that it sometimes says "--VISUAL--", but I can't find any links when I google these tiems.

Comment: Exactly which version of MonoDevelop, latest stable (2.6) or latest beta (2.8 beta2) ? FWIW I see a "INS" (for INSERT) in my status bar, which is the normal way to edit text, and have no issue making line selection using the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've enabled vi mode. Turn it off in MD preferences.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you. no idea how i switched this on but you have just rescued an wasted 2 hours and just prevented a macbook pro from being thrown out of a window. :)